# To Town Portal or Not to Town Portal?

Tags: dota-2

In DOTA 2, I find it important to be in my lane to get as much XP as I can in the begining of the game. But it happens, that I get ganked early on now and then. Often due to no warning from the other lanes.

**Should I use a Town Portal scroll to get back into my lane, or would the gold spend in this scroll just be a waste - or should I simply walk back into the lane and spare the gold?**

My thoughts on this, is wether its useless to Town Portal back due to such litle XP loss - or wether its highly important to get back into the lane asap.

Comment: If I may, i find the remark "Often due to no warning from the other lanes." curious and unnecessary. Playing Dota2  I often find players with this kind of attitude, always being ready to blame someone else for being killed or losing a match. I'm not saying it's not true, but even then, I find it perplexing that you had the urge to specify that here. It's the same with players who, at the end of the match say to everyone "report XXX", as to say "we didn't lose because I wasn't good enough, but because the rest/one of the team was bad".

Comment: @Duralumin Sorry if your offended. But its the true. So far its been due to a gank from another lane. I was not pointing fingers here. So Im kinda shocked about your note... And no, I'm surely not good enough to escape from a gank of 3 heroes, or to read the game properly.

Comment: No no, don't misunderstand; i wasn't offended, more like baffled. I too often die because of someone moving for a gank and the other lanes not calling mid in time. It happens. Sometime the ganker is shrewd and picks the right moment to move, sometimes the lanes are so concentrated on last hitting and such they don't notice. Sometimes having a couple of wards would prevent the gank. It's about feeling the necessity of annuncing to the world that it's someone else fault.  It happens often during or at the end of a game, and it's pointless.

Comment: During the game is only going to disrupt the teamwork further, and lower morale, at the end of the game nobody cares. If there were weaknesses in the team that made you lose, it means that the other team used those to win.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

As of patch 6.87, the cost of Town Portal Scroll has been reduced to 50 gold which make the answer to this question **yes**. If you have the gold then TP back to the lane. There are only two things you should concider before porting back to the lane :

- Do I risk to die within 60 seconds upon arrival ? If the answer is yes then you shouldn't probably TP there (at least alone).
- Will my help be needed in another lane within the next minute ? If yes then you should walk back to your lane and be ready to TP to the other lane.

Comment: One could argue that as a support, you should buy a TP, but not use it to just return to your lane; instead you should save that cooldown to quickly react and countergank your other lanes.

Comment: @patchandthat fair point, going to mention that

Answer (score 1):

The rule of thumb I use for this (in public games, not competitive):

If you're supposed to be last hitting on a lane (carry, solo mid) and the lane seems relatively safe, then TP back. Just a few last hits and you get your money back. You also desperately need the experience in these roles.

If you're not expecting to get any last hits (support), or the lane is pushed too far into enemy territory (solo offlane), TPing to that lane might be a waste. An alternative, especially as support, is to TP to a lane where the enemy doesn't expect you, and try to set up a gank there.

Answer (score 0):

You should use TP in the early game since you want to keep up with everyone but it really depends on your role. As a hero that needs farm or as a carry you deffinitely need to use TP to get back on your lane asap. As a support/forrest hero  you don't need it but it could be situational though. I don't think there are many guidelines related to using TP's since it depends on the game itself.